# C typedef const argument

Tags: c, typedef, declaration

```
typedef float vec3[3];

void test(vec3 const vptr) {
    *vptr = 1.f; // error: assignment of read-only location
    vptr[0] = 1.f; // error: assignment of read-only location
    vptr++; // no error
}
```

Is

```
vec3 const vptr
```

the same as

```
const vec3 vptr
```

for all typedefs? Is there any difference between last two? I thought

```
vec3 const vptr <==> float* const vptr // a constant pointer to an object
const vec3 vptr <==> const float* vptr // a pointer to a constant object
??? <==> const float* const vptr // a constant pointer to a constant object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typedef

```
typedef float vec3[3];
```

defines an alias for the array type `float[3]`

This declaration of the parameter

```
vec3 const vptr
```

declares `vptr` as having array type `const float[3]`.

Function parameters that are specified as having array types are adjusted to pointers to objects of the array element types.

So this declaration

```
vec3 const vptr
```

is adjusted to the type `const float *vptr`. That is it is a non constant pointer to a constant object.

This relation

> vec3 const vptr <==> float* const vptr // a constant pointer to an
>   object

is wrong. And this statement

```
vptr++; // no error
```

confirms that.

You can not get this declaration

```
const float* const vptr
```

using this typedef

```
typedef float vec3[3];
```

Comment: It's not so much that `vec3 const vptr` is adjusted to `const float *vptr`.   It's just that, for a function parameter, the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Peter They are not. Array parameters are actually adjusted to pointers in certain (basically all) circumstances. Vlad is more correct in saying adjusted, than ignoring this detail.